Pallet staking using assets pallet?
I'm trying to make pallet staking works with assets pallet. Lockable trait has already been implemented in a customized version of assets pallet but main issue remaining is that staking pallet issue or burn tokens when dealing with rewards, and Im working on a chain with fixed supply.
¿Do you have any suggestion? or Do you know of any example of some parachain or solochain having modified staking pallet to allow staking an asset instead of the currency token and having a fixed supply?
